# identify patterns within an array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I've got a question on identifying patterns within an array. I'm working with the following array:

```
A = [1.0, 1.1, 9.0, 9.2, 0.9, 9.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 9.2, 8.9, 1.1]
```

Now, this array is clearly made of elements clustering about `~1` and elements about `~9`.

Is there a way to separate these clusters? I.e., to get to something like:

```
a_1 = [1.0, 1.1, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 1.1]  # elements around ~1
a_2 = [9.0, 9.2, 9.1, 9.2, 8.9]  # elements around ~9
```

Thanks a lot. Best.

Comment: What would the delta between related values be?

Comment: Sorting sounds like a reasonable first step. Then, determine the mean and distribution? ... Isn't this a Brainstorming kind of question?

Comment: Yeah I know, I was thinking about sorting as well, but I was wondering whether there is a function or something to identify clusters within a list or array. If not, I'll proceed by sorting and getting the maximum step among values :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by comparing each element with which is closer. Is it closer to 1 or 9:

```
a_1 = [i for i in A if abs(i-1)<=abs(i-9)]
a_2 = [i for i in A if abs(i-1)>abs(i-9)]
```

But of course this is not a general solution for clustering. It only work in this case when you know the center of the cluster (1 and 9).

If you don't know the center of the cluster, I think you should use a clustering algorithm like [K-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

This is a simple K-Means implementation (with k=2 and 100 as limit iteration). You didn't need to know the center of the cluster, it picks randomly at first.

```
from random import randint

A = [1.0, 1.1, 9.0, 9.2, 0.9, 9.1, 1.0, 1.0, 1.2, 9.2, 8.9, 1.1]

x = A[randint(0,len(A)-1)]
y = A[randint(0,len(A)-1)]
for _ in range(100):
    a_1 = [i for i in A if abs(i-x)<=abs(i-y)]    
    a_2 = [i for i in A if abs(i-x)>abs(i-y)]    
    print(x,y)
    x = sum(a_1)/len(a_1)
    y = sum(a_2)/len(a_2)

print a_1
print a_2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, I don't know the 1 and 9 values a priori. I'd like to identify those values. That's the point of my question

Comment: Instead of `abs` you can use `if round(i) == 1` right ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar I don't think it works correctly when there are numbers near in the middle, let say 7

Comment: @urgeo in that case, I think you need a clustering algorithm, may be K-Means

Comment: @urgeo what malioboro said is exactly correct. You need some base for classification of these numbers ..other wise some numbers won't get as listed ex: 5

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. This is the exact purpose of a `k-means` algorithm where `k` is the number of groups needed and they are grouped by the recursive-mean distance between points relative to others. It is very easy to implement in Python. @malioboro You likely should update your answer to reflect k-means given that this would actually be the ideal solution for the problem.